# Ambiguous reference for label frame and '-' in swift 3 on updating to XCode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I updated Xcode to version 8.3 and on reopening my project started receiving the following errors.

1. Ambiguous reference to member '-'

   ```
   let frame = (frame: CGRect(x: 80.0, y: 140.0, width: ((self.view.bounds.size.width - 160.0)), height: 40))
   ```
2. Ambiguous reference to member 'frame'

   ```
   let frame2 = (frame: CGRect(x: 80.0, y: self.loginButton.frame.maxY + 40.0, width: (self.view.bounds.size.width - 160.0), height: 40))
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is that extra `frame:`?

Just do:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 80.0, y: 140.0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 160.0, height: 40)
```

and:

```
let frame2 = CGRect(x: 80.0, y: self.loginButton.frame.maxY + 40.0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 160.0, height: 40)
```